# how to get SharePoint site collection size data growth in last 6 months

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

we have a large sharepoint site collection with storing documents.

We want to check how its size in content database is growing for past 6 months?

Could anyone please share any useful links to get the information.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can get the content database growth rates from your `SQL server` by calculating the average growth rates of full database-backup sizes from backup system table.

check This [Transact-SQL script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/f1df9f50-9cd9-4c75-a8d9-e2faba6b8574) uses the backup history to analyse the growth of the databases size over a given period.

Other useful Sources: 
[Identify SQL Server Database Growth Rates](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3690/identify-sql-server-database-growth-rates/) 
[Database Growth History](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Growth/65757/)